# How do programs communicate with the kernel?

Tags: compilers, os-kernel

I am trying to understand how operating systems work because I would like to write my own version of Unix. Anyway, I have some doubts about some mechanisms that allow the applications to communicate with the kernel. In particular, according the several sources on the web, when we compile a program, it is OS dependent although the executable is a sequence of machine instructions. Well, if we compile a simple C program whose main aim is to print “Hello World”, I understand that the program calls the kernel with a trap when it’s time to print Hello World to the screen. Ok, but I am not sure which C instructions are handled by the operating system by syscalls and which are handled by the program itself: for example, how would a simple int i = 0 be handled?
The next question is about compiling the linux kernel. As I said above, when we compile and then execute a program, the operating system helps the program to perform certain low level tasks but what about the kernel? It is a program compiled on top of an operating system and it is written in C but it is not OS dependent. How would that be possible?
Another question: let’s say I write an assembly program as it happens in many computer science courses. Is that code OS dependent?

Comment: Starting from zero, it will take long time before you write your own OS. (Don't take this as a negative statement.)

Comment: Thank you but this does not matter. I want to learn! 

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  We ask that you do some research before asking, and provide some background and summary of what you've found so far.  In this case, I expect you'll find a lot that is useful in an operating systems textbook, and it would be better to spend some time with those basic resources first.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call

Comment: You program a virtual machine: a C machine - innards depending on environment. There may be a process executing (what compiler, linker, loader made of) your program, running on a virtual machine. Say, POSIX -  innards depending on environment. There may be generic parts of some kernel implementing system calls using calls to the device interface of - you guessed it - a virtual machine/device…

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/